# NOT send data to home page

Tags: c#-4.0

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @User.Identity.Name
    @:<p style="color:red" >Welcome,@User.Identity.Name</p>
    @Html.ActionLink("خروج", "Logout") 
}
else{
    @Html.ActionLink("ورود", "login")   
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("ثبت نام", "GetUser")
}
```

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is `false` and
`@User.Identity.Name is =""`

but i get data of login table and then login back to home page but I don't get data for showing `User.Identity.Name` why?

Please help me.

Comment: Aeemm, i don't see pure C# here?

Answer (score 1):

for checking authenticated users use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` :

```
@{
     if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         @User.Identity.Name
         <p style="color:red" >Welcome,@User.Identity.Name</p>
         @Html.ActionLink("خروج", "Logout")

      }
      else{
        @Html.ActionLink("ورود", "login")   
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink("ثبت نام", "GetUser")

      }
}
```

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` won't be set to true until the next request after calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`.

**if you are using IE** : Is IE blocking the cookie locally? Your privacy settings may be too restrictive. if is not , your way is correct to check authenticated users.